# Get auto width based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to get the exact value of width based on content, essentially I've this:

```
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Match1, Converter={StaticResource NameToWidthConverter}}" />
```

I've created a converter like this:

```
public class NameToWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value as string;

        switch (input)
        {
            case "V":
                return 20;
            case "N":
                return 20;
            case "P":
                return 20;
            default: //Larghezza per risultati
                return "Auto"; 
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

this working good but when `Auto` is returned in the compiler I get this error:

> ystem.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Auto' (type 'String');

the value Auto is however applied correctly, so what's wrong?

Comment: Avoid hard coding strings like that. If you make Match1 an enum, you won't need to change all converters when you change the magic word.

Comment: @shadow32 I can't use an enum, Match1 can contain different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return "Auto", you just return Double.NAN.

Comment: so what's your solution?

Comment: @Vandehusend -- Uh... what I said in my response?? return Double.NAN.